# How Safe Is It To Pass An URL With Token To Iframe SRC?

Tags: iframe

I need to authenticate an iframe that loads a site of a different domain.
I wanted to pass a JWT token through the src URL as follows:

```
<iframe src="https://otherdomain.com/landing?token=<token> />
```

otherdomain.com will then use the token I passed in the URL to authenticate its request.

Is this a safe approach or is the token sent over the wire in clear text?
Are there better ways to do this?